# Label each output of a multidimensional array being plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib

Working example:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def BoatFishSystem(state, t, *args):
    '''http://www.danham.me/r/2015/10/29/differential-eq.html'''
    A = args[0]
    B = args[1]
    C = args[2]
    fish, boat = state
    d_fish = fish * (A - boat - fish)
    d_boat = -boat * (B - C * fish)
    return [d_fish, d_boat]

A = 2.0
B = 1.0
C = 1.5
params = (A, B, C)
n_steps = 100000
t = np.linspace(0, 20, n_steps)
init_state = [1, 1]
species = odeint(BoatFishSystem, init_state, t, args = (params))

plt.plot(t, species, label = ['a', 'b'])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Desired result:
One output line is labelled 'a', the other one 'b'

Current result:
Both lines are labelled ['a', 'b']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the labels into `plt.legend()`:

```
plt.plot(t, species)
plt.legend(['a', 'b'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the answer.

Comment: You're welcome!  If this answer resolved your question, please mark it accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.